# Is the following claim 1 from patent (old lapsed patent A) considered prior art for the following patents & application(patents 1-4)?

Tags: prior-art, validity

[possible prior art(old lapsed patent A)](https://www.google.com/patents/US4617613?dq=ILLUMINATED%20ELECTRICAL%20OUTLET%20COVER%20PLATE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UB5OVNSpBtKzoQSxpoDABg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ)

[Active patent #1](https://www.google.com/patents/US8668347?dq=8,668,347&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ALVNVPzqI4f7oQSX-YH4DA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA)

[Active patent #2](https://www.google.com/patents/US6087588?dq=6087588&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IRNOVKLYKcHsoAS11YGwAg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA)

[Application patent #3](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130032594?dq=active%20cover%20plate&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8BVOVKulGc7hoAT6g4G4CA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA)

I am curious as to how the new patents were able to get approval on their claim 1 when it is very similar to a lapsed patent claim 1 and how possibly can the application may get approval? .

Comment: I have gone thorough the same thing. If there is even a less than 1% difference in your patent and the already available patent, you can file your application and most probably if the owner of lapsed patent guy don't put a claim, it will get approved. But exactly the same patent even if its lapsed wont get approved.

Comment: so if i use the claim from the lapsed patent to design a product. it would not infringe the newer patents since its prior art correct?

Comment: you cant use it directly. You need to prove that yours is different from lapsed one as lapsed guy may come back.